# Error message when trying to mock Stripe::Charge.create

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I am trying to mock out Stripe::Charge.create in my specs. (I know about stripe-ruby-mock, but I want to just mock it myself).

This is my code to mock:

```
expect_any_instance_of(Stripe::Charge).to receive(:create)
```

When I call my service object which calls `Stripe::Charge` in my specs I get this error message:

```
 Failure/Error: expect_any_instance_of(Stripe::Charge).to receive(:create)
   Stripe::Charge does not implement #create
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`create` is not a `Stripe::Charge` *instance* method but a *class* method.

Therefore you have to write:

```
expect(Stipe::Charge).to receive(:create)
```